# Configure dnssec with dnsmasq, how can I trust google public DNS?

Tags: security, dns, dnsmasq, google

I'm trying to configure a secured DNS service locally, so I use dnsmasq and queries google public dns with dnssec enabled.

So I will need to fetch the value for `trust-anchor`

```
# Uncomment to enable DNSSEC
dnssec
trust-anchor=xxx
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
trust-anchor=.,19036,8,2,49AAC11D7B6F6446702E54A1607371607A1A41855200FD2CE1CDDE32F24E8FB5
```

The values are taken from IANA
https://data.iana.org/root-anchors/root-anchors.xml